# awsProxy Rotating with Amazon API Gateway & Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, amazon-ec2, aws-api-gateway

I want to scrape some websites with selenium.

I successfully run the program with selenium on ec2 but, as we know, ec2 is associated with a specific IP. So I want to integrate Amazon API Gateway rotating proxy with my python selenium script.

I read [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55872164/how-to-rotate-proxies-on-a-python-requests) that integrates AWSGateway with the python requests module. How can I have a similar integration with selenium too??

Any guide would be appreciated.

Comment: Just to be clear: your need is to run your selenium script each time with a different IP so the remote scraped site is less likely to block your ip?

Comment: That's right. 
FYI - I'm aware of how to pass public proxies into selenium webdriver. But the downside of using public proxies is slowness & uptime. Hence I want to use AWS API-gateway to accomplish the same.

Comment: First of all, keep in mind that intensive scraping could stress target website and could lead to downtimes. If a website uses IP throttling or blocking I suppose they don't want to be scraped so frequently or at all and you should respect their work. Before proceed please think about it. That said, I suggest a different approach: 1) create an AMI of your EC2, 2) each time you need to run the script, start a SPOT instance base on that AMI, 3) Destroy the spot instance when the script has finished. In this way you will have a different public IP for each instance.

Answer (score 2):

You can try following Utility

- https://github.com/teticio/lambda-scraper

  ```
            import json
            import boto3

            num_proxies = 10
            url = 'https://ipinfo.io/ip'

            lambda_client = boto3.client('lambda')
            round_robin = 0
            while True:
                response = json.loads(
                    lambda_client.invoke(FunctionName=f'proxy-{round_robin}',
                                         InvocationType='RequestResponse',
                                         Payload=json.dumps({"url":
                                                             url}))['Payload'].read())
                print(f'{response["statusCode"]} {response["body"]}')
                round_robin = (round_robin + 1) % num_proxies
  ```

More detail how to use it you can find on following link -
https://medium.com/nerd-for-tech/web-scraping-with-a-proxy-pool-the-cheap-way-4c7d6fc9f859

This explain you how to use selenium with lambda using layer

- https://github.com/yai333/Selenium-UI-testing-with-AWS-Lambda-Layers
- https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/architecture/serverless-architecture-for-a-web-scraping-solution/

Comment: FYI - Lambda uses the same ip.