# Rotate IP using aws ApiGateway in selenium python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, aws-api-gateway

I want to rotate IP using aws ApiGateway.Got some idea from this guide: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68451842/14196595.
Want to implement it in selenium python.In guide "session" is used with ApiGateway but do not have any idea about using "session" in selenium python.
Or there is some other solution.
I know scraping websites is a violation of a website's Terms & Conditions but it's for only educational purposes want to know how to implement with selenium.

```
import json
import random
import os
import string
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

user_agents = [
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/17.1.2 Safari/605.1.1",
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/119.0.0.0 Safari/537.3",
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_6) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/13.1.2 Safari/605.1.1",
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/16.6 Safari/605.1.1"
    
    
    # Add more User-Agent strings as needed
]

chrome_options = Options()
#chrome_options.add_argument("--headless") 
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-popup-blocking")
chrome_options.add_argument("--profile-directory=Default")
chrome_options.add_argument("--ignore-certificate-errors")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-plugins-discovery")
chrome_options.add_argument("--incognito")
# Choose a random User-Agent from the list
random_user_agent = random.choice(user_agents)
chrome_options.add_argument(f"--user-agent={random_user_agent}")
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')
driver_service = Service(executable_path='C:\chromedriver\chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service = driver_service, options=chrome_options)

input_text = "Email marketing"
driver.get("https://mywebsite.com/")
driver.maximize_window()
# Find input text field
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[@type = 'text']")))
input_text_fname = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@id='topic']")

# Enter a value in the input text field
input_text_fname.send_keys(input_text)

# Click the button
button_element_IDEAS = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@type='submit']")))
#button_element_IDEAS = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[@type='submit']")
button_element_IDEAS.click()
subject_lines = []
# Find element
WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//ul//li[@class='TitleGeneratorResults_titleListItem__HAujF body']")))
time.sleep(10)  #must give
Title_Ideas = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//ul//li[@class='TitleGeneratorResults_titleListItem__HAujF body']")
for idea in Title_Ideas:
    subject_lines.append(idea.text)
# Extracting the first part of each string by splitting on '\n' and creating a new list
final_list = [item.split('\n')[0] for item in subject_lines]
# Converting the modified list to JSON format
json_output = json.dumps(final_list, indent=2)
print(json_output)
driver.quit()
```