# how can i send HTTP request with different IP addresses in python?

Tags: python, http, request, network-programming, ip

I have a server with five IP addresses(212.33.203.160 , 212.33.203.21,etc).
I want to send five HTTP POST requests with these IP addresses(each request with different IP).

How can I do this work in python?

Thanks.

Comment: Send the first request, then send the second one, etc.  What is the difficulty?

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48447709/python-requests-change-ip-address

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Requests, bind to an ip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12585317/requests-bind-to-an-ip)