# how to ip proxy in django route

Tags: python, django, nginx, proxy, reverse-proxy

There are websites like, "XYZ.com" and "ABC.com" and those websites can only be accessible with such a range of ip addresses.

We have public IP and using that third party website are accessible. (with only office premises we can access those website)

I have to develop a website (djangoproxy.com) in django so that I can access those third party websites from outside the public ip range.
so i plan to access those website like,
XYZ.djangoproxy.com,
ABC.djangoproxy.com
There is one condition, that access is based on only authenticated users. So I have to write code on djangoproxy.com for an authentic user. and after successfully login open a third party website in the same browser tab.

Had checked some python packages for vpn,
https://gist.github.com/Lazza/bbc15561b65c16db8ca8

Reference:
[Python requests, change IP address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48447709/python-requests-change-ip-address)

Can you guide me if this functionality can be developed using python code or any web-server configuration.
I am using NGINX as a web-server to host djangoproxy.com.

Comment: You want to use Django to create a proxy / VPN server? Why would you use Django for that? Use an actual proxy / VPN server...

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat there are may user using this with different device. how i can use VPN server user for all of them?

Comment: You can implement Proxy for that using NGINX or Apache

Comment: @BhavyaPeshavaria how we manage Proxy for authenticate user using NGINX or Apache? please share doc link

Comment: Found a better solution, posting it as answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [django-revproxy](https://django-revproxy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction.html#how-does-it-work) for your purpose. Your Django server will sit between the client and the external website. You can add the authentication logic of Django and allow proxy for only authenticated clients.